# Spotfire: Custom aggregation in summary table

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am creating a summary table in Spotfire using this code in IronPython:

```
def makeStatisticsVisTable(page, dt):
    table = page.Visuals.AddNew[TablePlot]()
    table.AutoConfigure()
    table.Data.DataTableReference = dt
    table.Title = "Statistics"
    sumTable = page.Visuals.AddNew[SummaryTable]()
    sumTable.AutoConfigure()
    sumTable.Data.DataTableReference = sampleTable
    sumTable.Title = "Summary"
    sumTable.Columns.Clear()
    for col in dt.Columns:
        table.TableColumns.Add(dt.Columns.Item[col.Name])
    for col in SampleColumns:
        sumTable.Columns.AddNew(col)
    sumTable.Aggregations.Clear()
    sumTable.Aggregations.AddNew("Count")
    sumTable.Aggregations.AddNew("Max")
    sumTable.Aggregations.AddNew("Min")
    sumTable.Aggregations.AddNew("Avg")
    sumTable.Aggregations.AddNew("StdDev")
    sumTable.Aggregations.AddNew("StdErr")
    return
```

I would like to include more aggregations using custom expressions, for example, something like this:

```
expr = "Max([Col1]) - Min([Col2])"
```

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Why not do these calculations in TERR instead? You can always format the data the comes out in IronPython / css but at least the calculations would be simple.

Comment: @AndrewPruet: do you have an example? I am limited, because the users should not need to do much by themselves, so I am scripting everything.